# Multiline Cell in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using the standard DataGrid control in Silverlight 4.
All data is readonly, i.e. no cell is editable.

Does anybody know how to display text in a cell such that it automatically wraps to the next line(s) (in the same cell) when the cell border is reached?

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In the column definition set the `TextWrapping` property to "Wrap":

```
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="Address"
        Width="150"
        Binding="{Binding Address}" >
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            </Style>
        </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Chrisf for your quick response. Your suggestion works. Well, kinda. What happens is that the text wraps when i manually narrow the width of the column. However, the column height remains even when i widen the column again (such that no wrapping would be necessary). Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @hhwh - I don't know off hand. I'd have to experiment, but looking at the resize events would be the best place to start.

Comment: Yes, I have started doing that. It does get rather involved, tho. There is no specific column header resize event. I can capture it in LayoutUpdated event but it gets rather messy to extract the info I am looking for. Which makes me think that there should be a more simple way I am not (yet) getting. I am fairly new to Silverlight. I will keep trying and learning in the process but any pointers you or anybody else may have would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to work.  Try using a template column, put the TextBlock in there set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to stretch and make sure to set the margins.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, rhooligan. tried it but row heights remain at their highest, even when i change column width manually such that wrapping is not needed.<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Media" Width="Auto">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Media, Mode=OneWay}"
              Margin="4,4,4,4"
              TextWrapping="Wrap"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>